# Пять соглашения или соглашений?

Tags: орфография

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильнее: «Было заключено пять соглашения (в рамках одного регпроекта)» или же «…соглашений»?

Answer (score 2):

Конечно же *пять соглашен**ий**!* Иначе только нерусский мог бы сказать.